# How to backup SDK before android studio crashes completely?

Tags: android, android-studio, backup, android-sdk-tools

last night my ***windows 8 crashed*** while it had android studio opened. Today the ***android studio acting funny specially when it comes to debugging. emulator and debugger does not seem to communicate well***.

i'm thinking about reinstalling the **android studio**. But *i don't want to download the whole **SDK** packs as they are large*. So before i reinstall Android studio **i want to backup the current SDKs** installed so i can reinstall them using the backup.

Is there a way to backup the **SDK** and how to reinstall them?

i'm using Android Studio 1.3.2

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `SDKManager` there you can see the path to SDK. Go to that path and backup the entire folder. Make sure you don't miss anything else SDK shows as broken.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me when Android Studio started acting wonky:

1. Select Android Studio `File` menu item `Invalidate Caches / Restart`
2. From Terminal command line run `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`

Answer (score 0):

Either you will do the longest way which is copying all the SDK in APP data or else check your anti-virus may be it will cause a lot for debugging mode.